# How to use my Eclipse CDT syntax coloring setup as my gVim color schemes?

Tags: vim, colors, eclipse, gvim

As Eclipse cannot show two pans of code simultaneously, I am used to using gvim to have it. But the color scheme / syntax coloring is different, what makes code review and comparisons hard.

Is there a (simple) way to have the same color scheme / syntax coloring in both tools ? How ? Is there exist a color scheme / syntax coloring converter tool somewhere ?

Comment: Did you try google before asking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Eclipse CDT supports two spans of code, like explained in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/696017/does-it-exist-an-eclipse-plugin-to-show-two-pans-of-code-simultaneously) post.
Twicking the syntax coloring of gvim to make it looks like the Eclispe one or vice-versa is very not easy, nor conveniant.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're after.
http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Many of the listed themes available using the Eclipse Color Theme plugin are ports or duplicates of existing Vim / Emacs color themes.

Comment: Good and usefull link, thank you. But I have defined my own color under Eclipse. An export feature between Eclipse and Vim color themes would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm not an eclipse user but this looks like a pretty easy way to do it.