# Does it exist an Eclipse plugin to show two pans of code simultaneously?

Tags: eclipse

As Eclipse cannot show two pans of code simultaneously, I am used to using gvim to have it. But it is unpractical.

Does it exist an Eclipse (CDT) plugin to show two pans of code simultaneously ?

Comment: Why do you say that it "cannot"?  It most certainly can, horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open 2 files in Eclipse, so that they reside on 2 separate tabs.

   [image: 2 files open in Eclipse]
2. Drag and drop one of the tabs to the right. Until the green split view preview shows the pane setup you want.

   [image: Split pane preview]
3. Release the mouse to enjoy your split pane view.

   [image]